# software not appearing in Ubuntu software

Tags: software-center

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 just now. I am searching software like ncbi-blast etc but they are not appearing in results. But these bioinformatics softwares used to appear before. ANy suggestions please!
thanks
raghul

Comment: `ncbi-blast` is still available: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ncbi-blast%2B . Yes, the new Ubuntu Software no longer shows many software that is in the repos.

Comment: You can see which PPAs have been disabled by the upgrade by inspecting `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list.distupgrade` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list.save`. The packaging system processes only `/etc/apt/sources.d/*.list`. See `man sources.list`. Check with the PPA provider to see if they provide a 16.04 (`Xenial`) release.

Answer (score 0):

The default **Software app** (Gnome Software) does not show the softwares which gained relatively less fame, at least I think so.

There is no software `ncbi-blast` in the repo, but there is software named `ncbi-blast+`. To install it:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open **Terminal** and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ncbi-blast+
```

You can install other packages by `sudo apt install <package_name>`.

If you are having problems, post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.